# Why don't providers have to be exported?

Tags: angular

I wonder why providers in Angular don't have to be exported, whereas components, directives and pipes have to be exported. So, the following code works perfectly fine:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    GreeterService
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

If I try to add `GreeterService` to the list of exports, of course I get the error:

```
Can't export value GreeterService from SharedModule as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

But why is this? Why do providers work directly, when I import the module they are provided in, but components, directives and pipes have to explicitly exported?

Comment: because exports work like the  subset of declarations that should be visible and usable in the component templates of other NgModules.

Comment: Do you mean: Only when I want to reference something in the component template, it has to be exported?

Comment: yes absolutely right.

Comment: So: this would mean, that I could declare a pipe, and without exporting it, use it in my component class. (not the template) but this does not work. I still have to export it, when I want to inject it in the component class.

Comment: if you don't need to include in SharedModule then include to your component like this
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
});
not direct access as pipe because it's a declaration and service is not  part of declarations.

Comment: This does not make it any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the fundamental concept of Services

- Services are decorated with @Injectable() metadata
- Which differentiates services from components/directive and can be used by providers to dynamically inject into required components.
- A provider tells an injector how to create the service. You must configure an injector with a provider before that injector can create a service (or provide any other kind of dependency).

Additionally the services are singleton for the application, shares same instance whereas components / directives can be multiple.

**More details**

- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection
- https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, but this does not clarify **why** providers don't have to be exported.

Comment: As explained here 

"Exports" property of Angular Module - is used for (which you want to make public)
The set of components, directives, and pipes declared in this NgModule that can be used in the template of any component that is part of an NgModule that imports this NgModule. Exported declarations are the module's public API.

https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule

Comment: But a service provider is part of the public api, isn't it?